# Using multiprocessing with shared memory for big global data

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, bigdata, shared-memory

I have a program that handles a lot of data(Gbs). To make it faster I decided to try multiprocessing.

The problem is that multiprocessing making copies of the data and that can't be done in my code due to large amount of data. My functions are using a lot of global variables but **for read-only**. I just want to parallelize one of them.

These functions are taking a list o stock names, and using them to access pandas data frame which is stored at a dict like: `frame=my_dict[stock_name]`. So I want to break my big name list at 12 sublists (6 cpu cores sto 12 processes), and call that specific function for each one of the 12 sublists at the same time.

So I am asking is there a way to use shared memory and when I am using keyword global, each different process can access that data? Or at least can I do that only for my big dictionary which contains my data frames?

This is the function:

```
def find_something2(threl=2.0, my_limit=150, far=365, mystocks=None):
""" Find stocks tha are worth buying"""
global current_date, total_money, reduced_stocks
worthing = list()
for stock in mystocks:
    frame = reduced_stocks[stock]
    temp = frame.loc[current_date:end_date]
    if not temp.empty:
        mydate = temp.head(far).Low.idxmin()
        my_min = temp.head(far).Low.min()
        if total_money >= my_min > 0:  # find the min date at four months
            ans, res, when_sell, total, income = worth_buy(stock, frame, mydate, 'Low',
                                                           thres=threl, sell_limit=my_limit)
            if ans:
                if income > 3 * 10 ** 6:
                    worthing.append([mydate, stock, res, when_sell, total, income])
```

Reduced_stocks is the dict I mentioned above

This function and the worth_buy function that it calls, does not made any changes to stored data,it is just returning some results.

I have also tried multithreading but due to global interpreter lock (GIL) it did not go any faster than the serial version

I am using a Windows 64 bit system

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using dataframes and dask (multiprocessing without doing it manually): https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/

Comment: this should be easier and faster? because i dont want to parallel a specific data frame, i want to checking many frames at the same time